# ESLint rule for Jasmine/Protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, eslint, protractor

> In Protractor, Jasmine expectations are patched to resolve WebDriver
>   promises implicitly.
>
> For instance, if you need to assert a count of certain elements, you
>   can use `count()` method (which returns a promise) directly:
>
> ```
> expect($$(".myclass").count()).toEqual(5);
> ```
>
> But, newcomers to Protractor can miss that and would do the same
>   resolving promises explicitly which leads to a more complex code:
>
> ```
> $$(".myclass").then(function (elements) {
>     expect(elements.length).toEqual(5);
> });
> ```

I've developed [an `ESLint` rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/use-count-method.md) to try to catch this kind of explicit "count" value check. The logic behind the rule is:

- It first locates the `.length` "member expression"
- Iterates over the ancestors and checks if inside `expect`
- Iterates over the ancestors and checks if inside a "then" callback and there is at least one argument passed to the callback function
- Determines if `.then` was called on an "element array finder"

```
'use strict'

/**
 * @fileoverview Recommend using `count()` instead of `then()` and `length`
 * @author Alexander Afanasyev
 */

var isElementArrayFinder = require('../is-element-array-finder')
var isThenCallBack = require('../is-then-callback')
var isExpect = require('../is-expect')

module.exports = {
  meta: {
    schema: []
  },

  create: function (context) {
    return {
      MemberExpression: function (node) {
        if (node.property && node.object && node.property.name === 'length') {
          // remember the variable name the ".length" was used on
          var variableName = node.object.name

          // find out if we are in an expect()
          var expectAncestor
          var thenAncestor
          var ancestors = context.getAncestors(node)

          for (var i = 0; i < ancestors.length; i++) {
            expectAncestor = ancestors[i]
            if (expectAncestor && expectAncestor.type === 'CallExpression' && isExpect(expectAncestor)) {
              // find out if we are inside a then callback
              ancestors = context.getAncestors(expectAncestor)
              for (var j = 0; j < ancestors.length; j++) {
                thenAncestor = ancestors[j]
                if (thenAncestor && thenAncestor.type === 'CallExpression') {
                  var thenCallback = isThenCallBack(thenAncestor)

                  // it has to have at least one argument
                  if (thenCallback && thenCallback.params && thenCallback.params.length > 0) {
                    var thenCallbackArgument = thenCallback.params[0]

                    // the same variable is a "then" callback function argument
                    if (thenCallbackArgument && thenCallbackArgument.name === variableName) {
                      // check that it was an ElementArrayFinder resolution
                      if (thenAncestor.callee && thenAncestor.callee.object) {
                        if (isElementArrayFinder(thenAncestor.callee.object)) {
                          context.report({
                            node: node,
                            message: 'Array.length inside promise resolution function detected. Use count() instead.'
                          })
                          return
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source code is also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/lib/rules/use-count-method.js).

---

The rule is overly complicated, very deep and nested and not readable at all (cyclomatic code complexity is 10). What refactoring methods would you apply to improve on readability?

<sup>FYI, using [`standard` style](https://standardjs.com/).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming of variables is good, they're mostly descriptive and easy to follow.

You could use [reverse conditional](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/reverseConditional.html) to reduce the cyclomatic code complexity, doing that your code would look something like:

```
module.exports = {
  meta: {
    schema: []
  },

  create(context) {
    return {
      MemberExpression(node) {
        if (!node.property || !node.property.object || node.property.name !== 'length') {
          return
        }

        const variableName = node.object.name

        const expectAncestors = context.getAncestors(node)
        for (const expectAncestor of expectAncestors) {
          if (!expectAncestor || expectAncestor.type !== 'CallExpression' || !isExpect(expectAncestor)) {
            continue
          }

          const thenAncestors = context.getAncestors(expectAncestor)
          for (const thenAncestor of thenAncestors) {
            if (!thenAncestor || thenAncestor.type !== 'CallExpression') {
              continue
            }

            const thenCallback = isThenCallBack(thenAncestor)
            const hasParams = thenCallback && thenCallback.params && thenCallback.params.length > 0

            if (!hasParams) {
              continue
            }

            const [thenCallbackParam] = thenCallback.params
            const paramIsDesiredVariable = thenCallbackParam && thenCallbackParam.name === variableName

            const isElementArrayFinderResolution = thenAncestor.callee && thenAncestor.calle.object && isElementArrayFinder(thenAncestor.callee.object)

            if (!paramIsDesiredVariable || !isElementArrayFinderResolution) {
              continue
            }

            context.report({
              node,
              message: 'Array.length inside promise resolution function detected. Use count() instead.'
            })

            return
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've included some extra changes in the above code, such as using some ES6.

- [Property shorthand](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand): `{ node: node }` -> `{ node }`
- [Method properties](http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties): `create: function(context) {` -> `create(context) {`
- [For-of](http://es6-features.org/#IteratorForOfOperator): `for (var i = 0; i < ancestors.length; i++) { expectAncestor = ancestors[i]` -> `for (const thenAncestor of thenAncestors)`, which is nice since the index was only used to access the `i`th element
- [Constants](http://es6-features.org/#Constants): Using `const` to denote variables that cannot be re-assigned
- Using param instead of "argument" to be consistent with eslint api
- Creating `expectAncestors`/`thenAncestors` instead of re-assigning `ancestors`

We could further refactor using [extract method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html):

```
const getExpectAncestor = (context, node) =>
  context.getAncestors(node).find(expectAncestor => expectAncestor && expectAncestor.type === 'CallExpression' && isExpect(expectAncestor))

const getThenAncestor = (context, expectAncestor) =>
  context.getAncestors(expectAncestor).find(thenAncestor => thenAncestor && thenAncestor.type === 'CallExpression')

const getThenCallbackParam = thenAncestor => {
  const thenCallback = isThenCallback(thenAncestor)
  const hasParams = thenCallback && thenCallback.params && thenCallback.params.length > 0

  if (hasParams) {
    return thenCallback.params[0]
  }
}

// Ideally you'd rename this something even more descriptive
const isDesiredVariable = (thenCallbackParam, variableName) => {
  const paramIsDesiredVariable = thenCallbackParam && thenCallbackParam.name === variableName
  const isElementArrayFinderResolution = thenAncestor.callee && thenAncestor.calle.object && isElementArrayFinder(thenAncestor.callee.object)

  return paramIsDesiredVariable && isElementArrayFinder
}

module.exports = {
  meta: {
    schema: []
  },

  create(context) {
    return {
      MemberExpression(node) {
        // You could extract this into a `isLengthVariable` function
        if (!node.property || !node.property.object || node.property.name !== 'length') {
          return
        }

        const expectAncestor = getExpectAncestor(context, node)
        if (!expectAncestor) {
          return
        }

        const thenAncestor = getThenAncestor(context, expectAncestor)
        if (!thenAncestor) {
          return
        }

        const thenCallbackParam = getThenCallbackParam(thenAncestor)
        if (!thenCallbackParam) {
          return
        }

        const variableName = node.object.name

        if (isDesiredVariable(thenCallbackParam, variableName)) {
          context.report({
            node,
            message: 'Array.length inside promise resolution function detected. Use count() instead.'
          })  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, we have extracted the main logic into seperate methods: `getExpectAncestor`, `getThenAncestor`, `getThenCallbackParam`

These methods are using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first element that matches the predicate provided. If no such element is found, it returns `undefined` and we can exit `MemberExpression`

**Further notes**

You could use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) shorthand since you are directly returning:

```
create = context => ({
  MemberExpression(node) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

You could declare `MemberExpression` outside of `module.exports` to further reduce the indentation level, though since the function relies on `context` you would need to pass `context` as an additional parameter. You could achieve this through a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function):

```
const MemberExpression = context => node => {
  // ...
}

module.exports = {
  // ...

  create: context => ({
    MemberExpression: MemberExpression(context)
  }
}
```

You'd probably want to refactor this further since there are some especially long lines when checking conditionals, you can use a formatter such as [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier)

Prettifying the solution with extracted methods gives the following:

```
const getExpectAncestor = (context, node) =>
  context
    .getAncestors(node)
    .find(
      expectAncestor =>
        expectAncestor &&
        expectAncestor.type === "CallExpression" &&
        isExpect(expectAncestor)
    );

const getThenAncestor = (context, expectAncestor) =>
  context
    .getAncestors(expectAncestor)
    .find(
      thenAncestor => thenAncestor && thenAncestor.type === "CallExpression"
    );

const getThenCallbackParam = thenAncestor => {
  const thenCallback = isThenCallback(thenAncestor);
  const hasParams =
    thenCallback && thenCallback.params && thenCallback.params.length > 0;

  if (hasParams) {
    return thenCallback.params[0];
  }
};

// Ideally you'd rename this something even more descriptive
const isDesiredVariable = (thenCallbackParam, variableName) => {
  const paramIsDesiredVariable =
    thenCallbackParam && thenCallbackParam.name === variableName;
  const isElementArrayFinderResolution =
    thenAncestor.callee &&
    thenAncestor.calle.object &&
    isElementArrayFinder(thenAncestor.callee.object);

  return paramIsDesiredVariable && isElementArrayFinder;
};

module.exports = {
  meta: {
    schema: []
  },

  create(context) {
    return {
      MemberExpression(node) {
        // You could extract this into a `isLengthVariable` function
        if (
          !node.property ||
          !node.property.object ||
          node.property.name !== "length"
        ) {
          return;
        }

        const expectAncestor = getExpectAncestor(context, node);
        if (!expectAncestor) {
          return;
        }

        const thenAncestor = getThenAncestor(context, expectAncestor);
        if (!thenAncestor) {
          return;
        }

        const thenCallbackParam = getThenCallbackParam(thenAncestor);
        if (!thenCallbackParam) {
          return;
        }

        const variableName = node.object.name;

        if (isDesiredVariable(thenCallbackParam, variableName)) {
          context.report({
            node,
            message: "Array.length inside promise resolution function detected. Use count() instead."
          });
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
```